# How to use MessageFormat to show one digit after decimal point for 0 and negative numbers as well

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to display only one digit after decimal point whether number is positive, negative or 0.

i am using following code -

```
<apex:outputText id="lblMarginTotalServicesRevenue" value="{0, number, ####,###,###.#}">
      <apex:param value="{!objPricingCalculator.Total_Services_Revenue__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

This is working fine for positive numbers but when number is 0 it is showing only 0 but i need 0.0 and for negative as well.
If number is -2000.98 it is showing only -2001 but i need -2000.9.

I want to stop rounding off.

Answer (score 3):

This will format the numbers consistently with one digit after the decimal point.

```
{0, number, #0.0}
```

The # character means show the digit if needed, the 0 means always show it. You can find out more about format strings in the docs [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_param.htm), which references the Java docs for more information (which is what Apex also uses internall) [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

The following...

```
public Decimal ANumber1 {get;set;}
public Decimal ANumber2 {get;set;}
public Decimal ANumber3 {get;set;}

public BlogController()
{
    ANumber1 = 2009.98;
    ANumber2 = -2009.98;
    ANumber3 = 2009;
}
```

And VF page...

```
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #0.0}">
          <apex:param value="{!ANumber1}" />
    </apex:outputText>
    <br/>
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #0.0}">
          <apex:param value="{!ANumber2}" />
    </apex:outputText>
    <br/>
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #0.0}">
          <apex:param value="{!ANumber3}" />
    </apex:outputText>
```

Results in ....

[image]

**Further info and Rounding**

This ensures that you always get a single digit after the decimal place. However the default behaviour of format string (as per the Java docs) is to round. There does not appear to be a way to control this in Apex / VF. If you require this you may have to resort to formatting this value in Apex and binding to a variable in your controller.

This [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) from Java (for which the Salesforce docs indicate is also applicable) will help describe the syntax of the formatting string. The # is used to show any digit, the 0 character is used to always show a numeric digit, even if it is not present. Hope this additional information helps you!

Comment: still It is rounding off the number.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I missed the 0 ahead of the decimal point. Try it now.

Comment: still It is rounding off the number -228.98 being shown as -229.0 :(

Comment: can you please tell me {0, number, ####,###,##0.00} what is each argument means in this declaration?

Comment: @PramodKumar: when you round -228.98 to one number it will round to -229. These format strings round, not truncate. If you need to truncate you might be better off casting them to a string and using that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more sample code and another documentation reference to help you.

Comment: If you're not a Java programmer, the 2nd link you gave to the reference in the Java docs from the Apex docs is very obtuse to read. The reference in your edit to the tutorial docs is far more useful to most of us who just need a quick answer (my personal thanks for that one).

Comment: @crmprogdev Yeah its true, i did find it a bit odd for Salesforce to reference it the first time I read their docs to be honest. Its a powerful feature and needs better docs for sure. I'll add it to my blog list! :)